# Git submodules: specify a specific SHA?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm referencing a git submodule in my project, and now need to reference a specific SHA in the target git repo.

```
# .gitmodules
[submodule "vendor/plugins/ssl_requirement"]
  path = vendor/plugins/ssl_requirement
  url = git://github.com/retr0h/ssl_requirement.git
```

The SHA I want is `bc96ad96407a72a60e0542cf3b0cecc6ff9e278e`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Submodules, by definition, always reference particular SHA1 in the subproject. That SHA1 isn't expressed in the `.gitmodules` file, but is instead expressed as the entry in the tree object that contains the submodule. The way you set this in git is by `cd`ing into the submodule, checking out the SHA1 you want, then `cd`ing back to the parent repo and committing your change, which will show up just like a changed file.

So in your case what you can do is

```
cd vendor/plugins/ssl_requirement
git checkout bc96ad96407a72a60e0542cf3b0cecc6ff9e278e
cd ..
git add ssl_requirement
# commit whenever you're ready
```

Comment: +1; that's almost exactly what I was just writing. Do note that if the submodule last fetched from origin before that commit, you might have to run `git fetch` in the submodule to fetch it!